# Why are there so many attacks on Imam Abu Hanifah RH (for example saying his hadiths have no value, that he is a liar, being compared to dajjal etc

Tags: hadith, sunni, madhhab, aqidah

Attack on Abu Hanifah RH by Ahmad bin Hanbal RH: Imam Hanbal said that a goats faecees is on par with the fatwas of Abu Hanifah
Source: Tarikh Al Baghdad Vol 13 pg 411

Imam Ahmad ibn Hanbal said Imam Abu Hanifah RH is a liar
Source:Tarikh al Baghdad vol 14 pg 418

Ahmad bin Hanbal RH condemns Abu Hanifah RH:
Risalaah thurjeeya Madhab Shaafee" by Imam Fakhradin Radhi, quoting "Al Alhfam" page233.

**I got these all from a website, please let me know if these are false or not.**

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help]. As to your inquiry: please check the following post that addresses your topic [did imam Malik say no one was born in Islam more harmful than abu Hanifa](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/74052/did-imam-maalik-really-say-no-one-was-born-in-islam-more-harmful-than-abuhanif). And if it answers your inquiry then mark this post as a duplicate of the one linked, else edit it and point out what your are missing in the given answer!